# How to externalise sslContextParameters

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel 2.20.0 and deploying a REST service using REST DSL with a HTTP scheme.

I'm referencing `sslContextParameters` with hard coded values and all works just fine.

I can't find a way of externalizing the resource into a properties file. So far I've tried with Camel `PropertiesComponent` and also Spring `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and `BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and I want to be able to do the following in the config:

```
<camel:sslContextParameters camelContextId="camelContext1" id="routeSSLContextParameters">
    <camel:keyManagers keyPassword="{{mypassword}}">
        <camel:keyStore password="{{mypassword}}"
            resource="{{mykeystore}}" type="JKS"/>
    </camel:keyManagers>
    <camel:trustManagers>
        <camel:keyStore password="{{mypassword}}"
            resource="{{mykeystore}}" type="JKS"/>
    </camel:trustManagers>
</camel:sslContextParameters>
```

I've also tried putting `${}` as per Spring properties, this also does not work.

Would it be possible to tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to your Spring Context and use the `${}` placeholder:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <!-- bridge spring property placeholder with Camel -->
    <!-- you must NOT use the <context:property-placeholder at the same time, 
    only this bridge bean -->
    <bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:com/stackoverflow/camel/labs/keys.properties" />
    </bean>

    <camel:camelContext id="exampleSsl" />  

    <camel:keyStoreParameters id="ksp" camelContextId="exampleSsl" resource="${keyStoreParameters.resource}" type="${keyStoreParameters.type}" provider="${keyStoreParameters.provider}" password="${keyStoreParamerers.password}" />
</beans>
```

The properties file:

```
keyStoreParameters.resource=/users/home/server/keystore.jks
keyStoreParameters.type=jks
keyStoreParameters.provider=jks
keyStoreParamerers.password=test
```

And the unit test:

```
public class SSLPlaceholderCamelTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(super.context);
        KeyStoreParameters ksp = (KeyStoreParameters)super.applicationContext.getBean("ksp");
        assertThat(ksp.getType(), is("jks"));
        assertThat(ksp.getProvider(), is("jks"));
        assertThat(ksp.getResource(), is("/users/home/server/keystore.jks"));
        assertThat(ksp.getPassword(), is("test"));
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/stackoverflow/camel/labs/SSLPlaceholderCamelTest.xml");
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Yeah, I've tested with `camel:sslContextParameters` and the properties weren't bidden. You could access it via context and [set programmatic (Setting Client Authentication On the Server Side)](http://camel.apache.org/camel-configuration-utilities.html):

```
KeyStoreParameters ksp = (KeyStoreParameters)context.getBean("keystore");
KeyStoreParameters tsp = (KeyStoreParameters)context.getBean("truststore");

KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
kmp.setKeyPassword("keyPassword");

SSLContextServerParameters scsp = new SSLContextServerParameters();
scsp.setClientAuthentication(ClientAuthentication.REQUIRE);
SSLContextParameters scp = (SSLContextParameters)context.getBean("sslContext");
scp.setServerParameters(scsp);
scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

SSLContext context = scp.createSSLContext();
SSLEngine engine = scp.createSSLEngine();
```

The `context`:

```
<camel:keyStoreParameters id="keystore"
    camelContextId="exampleSsl" resource="${keyStoreParameters.resource}"
    type="${keyStoreParameters.type}" provider="${keyStoreParameters.provider}"
    password="${keyStoreParamerers.password}" />

<camel:keyStoreParameters id="trustsore"
    camelContextId="exampleSsl" resource="${keyStoreParameters.resource}"
    type="${keyStoreParameters.type}" provider="${keyStoreParameters.provider}"
    password="${keyStoreParamerers.password}" />

<camel:sslContextParameters id="sslContext" camelContextId="exampleSsl" />
```

Just "autowire" it in your Camel Context.

Comment: Thankyou Ricardo - yes I did see this method on the JSSE section - my actual use case is to implement 2 way TLS with a separate keystore and truststore so with your method I don’t know how to tell Camel which is the keystore and which is the trust store - which is way I thought my original method was going to work - if only I could get the properties to work properly-I’m stuck

Comment: Hi! I've updated my answer. Try setting the keystore, trustore and SSLContextParameters in the Spring Context and then "wire them" together programmatically.

Comment: Hello Ricardo  - This does make sense - Would you be able to give me a hint on how to autowire the Java into my Camel context. Note that I am using Spring XML so I need to wire to Java class - I've searched all day to see if this is possible.

Comment: @nickb I’m away from keyboard right now, but you may have to take the Spring Context during the camel startup and get the beans from the context by their id. Please see the docs from Apache Camel JSSE (specifically the programmatic part) and take a look at the examples. Arriving at the office I’ll try to create a little example for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the end:

1.Use Spring/Camel properties bridge:

```
<bean class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" id="springProperties">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
</bean>
```

2.Set up the SSLContext Parameters from Spring:

```
   <bean class="org.apache.camel.util.jsse.SSLContextParameters" id="routeSSLContextParameters">
        <property name="keyManagers" ref="routeKeyManagers"/>
        <property name="trustManagers" ref="routeTrustManagers"/>
        <property name="serverParameters" ref="routeSSLContextServerParameters"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.util.jsse.KeyManagersParameters" id="routeKeyManagers">
        <property name="keyStore" ref="routeKeystore"/>
        <property name="keyPassword" value="${keyStorePassword}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.util.jsse.TrustManagersParameters" id="routeTrustManagers">
        <property name="keyStore" ref="routeTruststore"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.util.jsse.SSLContextServerParameters" id="routeSSLContextServerParameters">
        <property name="clientAuthentication" value="REQUIRE"/>
    </bean>
    <keyStoreParameters id="routeKeystore" password="${keyStorePassword}" resource="${keyStoreResource}" type="JKS" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"/>
    <keyStoreParameters id="routeTruststore" password="${trustStorePassword}" resource="${trustStoreResource}" type="JKS" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"/>
```

3. Reference the SSLContext in the restconfiguration

   ```
   <restConfiguration apiContextPath="api-docs" bindingMode="json" component="restlet" contextPath="/mytest" enableCORS="true"
       host="localhost" port="9090" scheme="https">
       <endpointProperty key="sslContextParameters" value="#routeSSLContextParameters"/>.....
   ```